# How should I pass secrets (RDS password) into my Lambda function created by CloudFormation/SAM?

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, aws-lambda

I created my RDS database and Lambda function using CloudFormation/AWS SAM. I currently passed in my DB connection info via envrionment variables but am unsure if thats the recommended way since in the AWS dashboard, I can see the password in clear text

```
TestApiFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    DependsOn: DB
    Properties:
      Handler: src/test.handler
      FunctionName: Test
      VpcConfig:
        SecurityGroupIds:
          - !Ref DataTierSecurityGroup
        SubnetIds:
          - !Ref PrivateSubnet1
          - !Ref PrivateSubnet2
          - !Ref PrivateSubnet3
      Environment:
        Variables:
          'DB_HOST': !GetAtt DB.Endpoint.Address
          'DB_USER': !Ref DBUser
          'DB_PASSWORD': !Ref DBPassword
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [IAM database authentication](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.html) to use an IAM role instead of a username and password to connect to your database, if you're using MySQL or MySQL-compatible Aurora.

You would just need to turn on IAM database authentication on the RDS instance, create the role with `rds-db:connect` permission, and attach the role to the Lambda function. [This article](https://cloudonaut.io/passwordless-database-authentication-for-aws-lambda/) goes into more detailed instructions for setting this up.

Unfortunately, it doesn't look like you can enable IAM database authentication from CloudFormation, so if that is a no-go or if you're not using a compatible database engine, you can also look into [AWS Secrets Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/intro.html). You would need to create an [IAM role that can access your Secrets Manager secrets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/auth-and-access_identity-based-policies.html) and attach that role to your Lambda function. One benefit of this approach is that [AWS provides secrets rotation out-of-the-box](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/rotating-secrets-lambda-function-overview.html) for you for RDS usernames/passwords.

Answer (score 0):

So dont pass the credential directly via Cloudformation. Make your lambda get credential by reading from dynamodb, parameter store (SSM) or AWS secret.

- Parameter store show **** for password
- With DynamoDB you can restrict view to certain users.
- AWS secret is another service that allow you to store secret in key:value

Comment: Systems Manager (SSM) is a fantastic idea. IAM paswordless RDS access from Lambda is problematic since Amazon recommends max 20 connections with it and with Lambda there is no way to correctly manage the number of connections to RDS to keep them under 20. SSM will work great in that aspect.